# Groovy - reformatting JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I have a json structure which looks like this

```
  {
   "Fields":[
      "FieldName1",
      "FieldName2",
      "FieldName3",
      "FieldName4",
      "FieldName5"
   ],
   "Rows":[
      {
         "Values":[
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Values":[
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Values":[
            "K",
            "L",
            "M",
            "N",
            "O"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The field names, and the number of fields, are not fixed.
Im trying to reformat it, as

```
{
   "values":[
      {
         "FieldName1":"A",
         "FieldName2":"B",
         "FieldName3":"C",
         "FieldName4":"D"
      },
      {
         "FieldName1":"E",
         "FieldName2":"F",
         "FieldName3":"G",
         "FieldName4":"H"
      },
      {
         "FieldName1":"I",
         "FieldName2":"J",
         "FieldName3":"K",
         "FieldName4":"L"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any thoughts on how it's possible to do this in such a way that the reformatting works, regardless of the number of fields and the field names please?

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: use JsonSlurper to parse it, then transform maps/arrays using code, then JsonBuilder or JsonOutput to format objects back to json.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I got to the point where the code is adding each of these to a list:

[FieldName1: { 'A' }, FieldName2: { 'B' }, FieldName3: { 'C' }, FieldName4: { 'D' }, FieldName5: { 'E' }]

[FieldName1: { 'F' }, FieldName2: { 'G' }, FieldName3: { 'H' }, FieldName4: { 'I' }, FieldName5: { 'J' }]

[FieldName1: { 'K' }, FieldName2: { 'L' }, FieldName3: { 'M' }, FieldName4: { 'N' }, FieldName5: { 'O' }]

but then it didn't look right in the debugger and the elements weren't split out- it just got added as three strings

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map with field names and indices, then add field name for each value by index

something like this

```
        def input = new JsonSlurper().parseText(TEXT)
        def fieldNamesByIndex = input["Fields"].indexed()
        def values = input["Rows"].collect { it["Values"] }.collect { values ->
            // values.withIndex creates a list of Tuple<String, Integer>, where string is the value and integer is the index
            return values.withIndex().collectEntries { [(fieldNamesByIndex[it.second]): it.first] }
        }

        def output = ["values": values]
        println(JsonOutput.toJson(output))
```

Comment: that's genius. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to assume, that you got the loading/writing part of the JSON
down from your comment.

The easiest way to get from a list of keys and a list of values to a map
is via `[keys,values].transpose().collectEntries()`.  So you would have
to iterate the `Rows` and do that.  For the result place that into a map
under the key `values`.

```
[values: data.Rows.collect{ [data.Fields, it.Values].transpose().collectEntries() }]
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version to skin a cat:

```
import groovy.json.*

def map = [
   "Fields":[
      "FieldName1",
      "FieldName2",
      "FieldName3",
      "FieldName4",
      "FieldName5"
   ],
   "Rows":[
      [
         "Values":[
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E"
         ]
      ],
      [
         "Values":[
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J"
         ]
      ],
      [
         "Values":[
            "K",
            "L",
            "M",
            "N",
            "O"
         ]
      ]
   ]
]

def values = map.Rows*.Values*.withIndex()*.collectEntries{ v, ix -> [ map.Fields[ ix ], v ] }
def res = [ values:values ]

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint( JsonOutput.toJson( res ) )
```

prints

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "FieldName1": "A",
            "FieldName2": "B",
            "FieldName3": "C",
            "FieldName4": "D",
            "FieldName5": "E"
        },
        {
            "FieldName1": "F",
            "FieldName2": "G",
            "FieldName3": "H",
            "FieldName4": "I",
            "FieldName5": "J"
        },
        {
            "FieldName1": "K",
            "FieldName2": "L",
            "FieldName3": "M",
            "FieldName4": "N",
            "FieldName5": "O"
        }
    ]
}
```